# How to mix audio/music files by FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

First of all, is it a good idea to use FFMPEG as a music mixer?

I want to mix audio files of separate instruments to build the music (all `wav` files and similarly recorded).

How can I tell `FFMPEG` to mix *n* audio files according to a time map like

```
audio1.wav from 0 to 60s
audio2.wav from 3.5 to 18s
audio3.wav from 10 to 17s
audio4.wav from 61 to 90s
```